# Can I change the list of Priority values for tickets in Jira?

Tags: jira

Jira → Issues → Create Issue → Priority field has these values:

- Blocker
- Critial
- Major
- Minor
- Trivial

Can this list be changed?

Comment: You can also select one of the values as a default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions to do this can be found [in the manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Defining+%27Priority%27+Field+Values):

> 1. Log in as a user with the **JIRA Administrators** global permission.
>      Select **Administration > Issues > Priorities** to open the View
> 2. Edit the existing priorities or you can add your own.